# How to jasmine test jquery getJSON success response

Tags: jquery, jasmine

I am very new to testing with jasmine. I am wondering how to test the success response of my getJSON call as described below? Any help is much appreciated. Here are both my files.

RandomSpec.js

```
describe("Random",function(){
  var random;

  beforeEach(function(){
    random = new RandomInit();
  });

  describe('quote',function(){
    it('should return a string',function(){
      random.quote();
      // HOW TO TEST SUCCESS RESPONSE???
    })
  });

});
```

Random.js

```
function RandomInit(){

}

RandomInit.prototype.quote = function(){
  (function() {
    $.getJSON("http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&key=457653&format=jsonp&lang=en&jsonp=?")
        .done(function (json) {
          console.log('json: '+json);
        })
        .fail(function(jqxhr,textStatus,error){
          var err = textStatus +','+error;
          console.log('Stuff got broke: '+ err)
        });
  })();
};
```